# UTC Date/Time String to Timezone

Tags: php, timezone, utc

How do I convert a date/time string (e.g. 2011-01-01 15:00:00) that is UTC to any given timezone php supports, such as America/New_York, or Europe/San_Marino.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

PHP's [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) object is pretty flexible.

```
$UTC = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
$newTZ = new DateTimeZone("America/New_York");
$date = new DateTime( "2011-01-01 15:00:00", $UTC );
$date->setTimezone( $newTZ );
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: This is it. You did it!

Comment: Its so flexible it even takes `$text = '2019-02-15T17:10:46+05:30'; $dateTime = new DateTime($date); echo $dateTime->format("M d, Y");`

Comment: @Sorter yes, you can return a date like that and format it, but this question was specifically about converting timezones. Since your datetime string already includes the TZ in it (OPs did not), you can skip the part where I set `$UTC` on the `new DateTime` call and add `$UTC` to the `setTimezone` call instead, transforming your TZ into UTC from `+5:30`!

Comment: I've been battling this for a day and a half! This was what I needed!

Answer (score 5):

PHP's [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) object is pretty flexible.

Since the user asked for more than one timezone option, then you can make it generic.

**Generic Function**

```
function convertDateFromTimezone($date,$timezone,$timezone_to,$format){
 $date = new DateTime($date,new DateTimeZone($timezone));
 $date->setTimezone( new DateTimeZone($timezone_to) );
 return $date->format($format);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
echo  convertDateFromTimezone('2011-04-21 13:14','UTC','America/New_York','Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**Output:**

2011-04-21 09:14:00

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the UTC is not included in the string then:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$datestring = '2011-01-01 15:00:00';  //Pulled in from somewhere
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s T',strtotime($datestring . ' UTC'));
echo $date;  //Should get '2011-01-01 10:00:00 EST' or something like that
```

Or you could use the DateTime object.

Answer (score 1):

```
function _settimezone($time,$defaultzone,$newzone)
{
$date = new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone($defaultzone));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($newzone));
$result=$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
return $result;
}

$defaultzone="UTC";
$newzone="America/New_York";
$time="2011-01-01 15:00:00";
$newtime=_settimezone($time,$defaultzone,$newzone);
```

Answer (score 0):

General purpose normalisation function to format any timestamp from any timezone to other.
Very useful for storing datetimestamps of users from different timezones in a relational database. For database comparisons store timestamp as UTC and use with `gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

```
/**
 * Convert Datetime from any given olsonzone to other.
 * @return datetime in user specified format
 */

function datetimeconv($datetime, $from, $to)
{
    try {
        if ($from['localeFormat'] != 'Y-m-d H:i:s') {
            $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat($from['localeFormat'], $datetime)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        }
        $datetime = new DateTime($datetime, new DateTimeZone($from['olsonZone']));
        $datetime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($to['olsonZone']));
        return $datetime->format($to['localeFormat']);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

***Usage:***

> ```
> $from = ['localeFormat' => "d/m/Y H:i A", 'olsonZone' => 'Asia/Calcutta'];
>
> $to = ['localeFormat' => "Y-m-d H:i:s", 'olsonZone' => 'UTC'];
>
> datetimeconv("14/05/1986 10:45 PM", $from, $to); // returns "1986-05-14 17:15:00"
> ```

Answer (score -2):

How about:

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$date = new DateTime('2011-04-21 13:14', $timezone);
echo $date->format;
```

Comment: `$date->format()` requires 1 parameter. See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Comment: $date = new DateTime('2011-04-21 13:14', $timezone)  Isn't this missing the seconds for UTC?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this code (even if fixed to use `format` as method) doesn't convert between time zones as requested: `$date` will be at UTC.