# Changing timezones with Date function in PHP

Tags: php, date

Im trying to assign a variable with timezone info that will change the time of info saved in a database.

Here is my code that doesn't work:

```
<?php 
$timeZone = "- 3600";
$date = date('His', time() $timeZone);
echo $date;
?>
```

But when I do this it works...

```
<?php 
$date = date('His', time() - 3600);
echo $date;
?>
```

Why won't the variable work in there?

Comment: One is a string, the other an integer ...

Comment: Hm, in seconds you say? Normally I'd advocate [`DateTime::setTimeZone()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php), but it would mean processing your timezones... And your current code doesn't work because code in variables isn't executed, how could I ever have a `$string='exit';` otherwise without shutting PHP down?

Comment: This isn't shell. Variables don't expand in code to their (string) contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's invalid syntax. Change `$timeZone` to an integer and add it to `time()`.

```
$timeZone = -3600;
$date = date('His', time() + $timeZone);
echo $date;
```

[See a demo](http://codepad.org/lBMNHnj1)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert to another timezone, there is a proper way of doing it: [UTC Date/Time String to Timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746531/php-utc-date-time-string-to-timezone)

Comment: this is the way to go. Don't get stuck using epochs

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed binary operators in a string and expect them to execute.  You'll need to do something like this:

```
<?php 
$timeZone = -3600;
$date = date('His', time() + $timeZone);
echo $date;
?>
```

Comment: That's not a binary operator, it's an arithmetic operator. But the same principal applies.  :)

Comment: @Nerdwood Operators can be grouped according to the number of values they take. Unary operators take only one value, for example ! (the logical not operator) or ++ (the increment operator). Binary operators take two values, such as the familiar arithmetical operators + (plus) and - (minus), and the majority of PHP operators fall into this category.

Comment: I do apologise, I thought you were talking about bitwise operators (using binary values). The minus sign, however, can be used as both a unary (negation) and binary (subtraction) operator.