# time using asTime() not correct

Tags: php, yii2, amazon-rds

in my Grid view i have this to change the column time and date to use my timezone

```
[
    'format' => [
       'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
       'timeZone' => 'Asia/Singapore',
    ],
    'attribute' => 'created_at',
    'label' => 'Date',
    'filter' => false,
    'value'=> function($model, $key, $index, $column){ return Search::getDateTime($model); }, }
    'format' => 'raw',
]
```

then in my search model i have this

```
public static function getDateTime($model) {

        $date = Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->created_at);
        $time = Yii::$app->formatter->asTime($model->created_at);

        return Html::a($date, null, ['href' => 'javascript:void(0);', 'class' => 'btn btn-link p-0 rounded-0 tooltips', 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip', 'data-placement'=> 'bottom', 'title' => $time]);
    }
```

i also have this in my main.php components

```
'formatter' => [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
            'dateFormat' => 'php:j M Y',
            'datetimeFormat' => 'php:d/m/Y h:i a',
            'timeFormat' => 'php:H:i A',
            'defaultTimeZone' => 'Asia/Singapore'
        ],
```

in my database the `created_at` is saved like this `2021-11-22 11:28:16` UTC

how do i get it to show the correct time based on my timezone? (Asia/Singapore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your saved datetimes are date and time, but no reference to UTC zone. So, it's impossible to autoformat them to Asia/Singapore datetime. Instead of that, as you know that they are UTC, and Asia/Singapore is UTC+8, you can add 8 hours to your datetimes.

So, I added code to:

- Create a DateTime object from the created_at field value.
- Add 8 hours to it.
- Get new created_at value, with 8 hours added.
- And go ahead with your original code.

Here you are:

```
public static function getDateTime($model)
{
    $datetime = new DateTime($model->created_at, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    $datetime->add(new DateInterval('PT8H'));
    $created_at = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $date = Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($created_at);
    $time = Yii::$app->formatter->asTime($created_at);

    return Html::a($date, null, ['href' => 'javascript:void(0);', 'class' => 'btn btn-link p-0 rounded-0 tooltips', 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip', 'data-placement'=> 'bottom', 'title' => $time]);
}
```

And here is another (maybe better) way to convert datetime from UTC to specific time zone:
[UTC Date/Time String to Timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746531/utc-date-time-string-to-timezone)

Comment: is there a way do set this globally? or do i have to it every time i use `asDate()` and `asTime()` ? because all my datetimes are saved in DB as date and time.

Comment: I use to set time zone for my entire web application, using date_default_timezone_set(). This way, my system is in the time zone I want, and datetimes are saved in DB according to that time zone, so I can use them as they are stored.

Comment: Using `Europe/London` is bad idea. UK is using daylight saving time system so that timezone would use UTC for dates in winter but UTC+1 for dates in summer. You should use `new DateTimeZone('UTC')` instead if your times are always saved as UTC.

Comment: @MichalHynčica You're right, I've edited my answer thank you!